# Enterprise Architect Reverse Engineering: PHP "Unexpected symbol: [ "

Tags: php, laravel, enterprise-architect, component-diagram

I'm trying to create component diagrams in PHP with reverse engineering using Enterprise Architect tool. But it occurs errors when I try to perform it. These are the error logs:

```
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Client.php  on line 9.  Unexpected symbol: [   
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Sensor.php  on line 9.  Unexpected symbol: [   
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Site.php  on line 9.  Unexpected symbol: [ 
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\User.php  on line 17.  Unexpected symbol: [    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Client.php  on line 9.  Unexpected symbol: [   
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Sensor.php  on line 9.  Unexpected symbol: [   
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Site.php  on line 9.  Unexpected symbol: [ 
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\User.php  on line 17.  Unexpected symbol: [    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Client.php  on line 10.  Unexpected symbol: ,  
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Sensor.php  on line 10.  Unexpected symbol: ,  
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Site.php  on line 10.  Unexpected symbol: ,    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\User.php  on line 18.  Unexpected symbol: ,    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Client.php  on line 9.  Unexpected symbol: [   
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Sensor.php  on line 9.  Unexpected symbol: [   
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\Site.php  on line 9.  Unexpected symbol: [ 
There was an error parsing C:\Users\Utente\Dropbox\FourBit\Ingegneria\PROGETTO\Componenti Progetto\Class\User.php  on line 17.  Unexpected symbol: [
```

For example, the following is the code of **Client.php**:

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Client extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'PI', 'BusinessName'
        ];

        public function address()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Address::class);
        }

        public function users()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(User::class);
        }
```

The error parsing is on **protected $fillable = [
            'PI', 'BusinessName'
        ];**
I don't know if this can help you, but I'm using as framework Laravel.
Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: It would seem your "Enterprise Architect tool" does not recognize new PHP array syntax.

Comment: Outdated php version^, also, you have 6 questions, none of which you have selected the correct answer on. If an answer solves you problem, mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

As the others pointed out, the `$array = [ 'key' => 'value' ];` syntax was introduced in php 5.4
by default in ea, php generation uses version 5.3, but you can change it to 5.6.
Follow these screenshots:
[image: Click the Configure ribbon then the Options Menu]
[image: Once in the Manage project Options dialog, you can change the default version for PHP]

Answer (score 2):

Check your PHP Version, the array syntax `$array = [ 'key' => 'value' ];` was only introduced in PHP 5.5 (I believe) so anything less will cause a syntax error.

Comment: It was actually introduced in PHP 5.4

Comment: Do you know another tool that can do reverse engineering on PHP code to create component diagrams?